# How to VACUUM a Core Data SQLite db?

Tags: sqlite, core-data, vacuum

By design, Core Data does not issue a **VACUUM** SQL command to its SQLite database(s), as [detailed here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2008/3/5/200554).  I'm creating a Core Data application that'll store, and later delete, large binary files (2-10MB in size) in a SQLite db.  Over time this will lead to fragmentation and a larger-than-necessary SQLite database.  I'd like to periodically issue a VACUUM command, say, during a cleanup operation I run.

- How can I progmatically issue a VACUUM command to Core Data's SQLite stores?
- Is it possible to do this through Core Data, or must I mount the SQLite db and connect to it directly to execute the VACUUM SQL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The supported way to do this, on OS X 10.6 / iOS 3.0 and later, is to set the [NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Store_Options) in the options when you are adding the store to the persistent store coordinator.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can `vacuum` your **CoreData** container

Example:

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "someName")

// Enable history tracking and remote notifications
guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
    fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to retrieve a persistent store description.")
}

description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption)

//... The rest of your setup
```

By doing this, the **CoreData** container will perform the `vacuum` command and thus resize itself accordingly.

Comment: It seems weird that setting an *option* causes an immediate *action*.  Is it just me?  I presume that this NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption remains *true* after them vacuum is complete.  Does it have any additional effects later?

Comment: @Jerry Krinock Option key to rebuild the store file, forcing a database wide defragmentation when the store is added to the coordinator. This invokes SQLite's VACUUM command. It is ignored by stores other than the SQLite store.https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nssqlitemanualvacuumoption?changes=_7_3_2&language=objc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `vacuum` is a recognized SQL statement in SQLite. It can be used as a normal query, [or so it says](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#sql-stmt).

Beware, though, as it can lead to excessive file system reads and writes—the bottleneck of practically any system—not to mention server file system fragmentation on Windows servers.

Comment: The question is how to execute it via Core Data, not whether it exists.